# Swift Xcode 6 developer baseball counter

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

At the end of my code I'm trying to make it when we get 3 strikes the outs go up by one.  I'm getting an error at the bottom if statement.  it says expected declaration

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  helloWordDemo
//
//  Created by Developer on 6/8/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 AECApps. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBOutlet var labelDispaly : UILabel = nil
// dispaly Strikes

var counter = 1

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender : AnyObject) {

    labelDispaly.text = "Strikes \(counter++)"
}
//button to add strikes

@IBOutlet var OutsDispaly : UILabel = nil

var outsCounter = 1
//outs dispaly

@IBAction func outsButtonPressed(sender : AnyObject) {

    OutsDispaly.text = "Outs \(outsCounter++)"

}
//button to add outs
if counter = 3 {
    outsCounter ++
   }
}
```

Comment: Your code with the `if` statement is not inside any function

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the if statement is not inside a function. This is OK when the statement is outside the `class`, but is not in this case. Write a function to run the statement. Add this to your class:

```
func updateOuts(){
    if counter == 3 {
        outsCounter++
    }
}
```

Also, inside if statements you should use `==` instead of `=`. This is because `==` compare two values and `=` sets a variable.

Comment: lol so how would i do that

Comment: Add this function to your class and call it whenever you need to update the `outsCounter`.

Comment: omg i feel stupid can you post the finished code

Comment: I just tried it and i can't get it to wark